# What does blinking power light of a laptop indicate?

Tags: hard-drive

Today i connected my laptop to its power adapter (which has been down for past few weeks due to hdd failure) to charge it before i could change the drive.
When i turn on the AC power, the power light on the front panel goes solid bright for a few seconds then starts blinking. I know my battery was 63% damaged before laptop crashed but it worked fine.
I read a hard reset after detaching the battery would solve it but to no avail.

What causes this power light to blink?

I have HP DV4-2126TX

Comment: The user guide or technical documentation for your specific laptop should list the meaning of this notification and others. If you no longer have the manuals, you can go to the HP site and download them. http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4074361&taskId=135

Answer (score 2):

Most likely cause for blinking is that the laptop is turned on and in standby or similar.

... but it is different on every laptop.

Sometimes it means that it's charging the battery.

Sometimes blinking lights might even indicate a hardware failure (for instance, a failed battery, or damaged motherboard, or some other issue).

You would have to reference your laptop's user manual for more information on how to interpret these lights. There is no standardized method of using indicator lights, especially in laptops.

Comment: One solution was Remove battery, hard reset, start laptop on AC, reseat battery. is it safe?

Comment: +1 for failed battery.  My Toshiba, Dell and Lenovo all do this when battery is "bad"